# How do you fix peerDependency when building a TS plugin in VSCode

Tags: typescript, plugins, visual-studio-code, peer-dependencies

I am currently building a plugin using TS which has some peer dependencies. I had to add [install-peers-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/install-peers-cli) to make sure it installs the peers without changing `package.json` and the build works fine with no issues.

Now the issue is that inside of VSCode, I am still getting the following for all of my peer dependencies.

```
Cannot find module 'moment-timezone'.ts(2307)
```

Just wondering if there is a way to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this one...

```
npm i install-peers -D
```

Comment: this is good. Just to add in the case you need to trigger prepare script and build on the consumer side

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @jonathan-mwaniki is good enough for making it work. Just to add in the case you need to trigger prepare script and build on the consumer side, add `npm i install-peers -D` to prepare script like this:

```
    "prepare": "npm i install-peers -D && npm run build"
```